# Cannot add a table to database in Server Explorer in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, mdf, server-explorer

[image]

Hello! No "Add New Table" item in context menu. How to fix that? I have sql server data tools for vs2013 already installed on my pc.